# Binding Data in onblur event of textbox?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've a JavaScript function to check the value entered by the user and it should not be more than the value which comes from database. I have code like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNoDays" runat="server" Width="49px" onblur="return NumericChk(this,'<%=v_days%>')"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use ASP.NET `RangeValidator` or `CompareValidator` control.

Try this,

Markup

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function NumericChk(obj, val) {
            if (obj.value > val) {
                obj.focus();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" 
                     runat="server">         
        </asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>
```

Add the "onblur" attribute via code-behind.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            int value = 10;
            string handle=string.Format("return NumericChk(this,{0})",value);
            TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onblur", handle);
        }
    }
```

Comment: But value come from database dynamically in page load.